# Efficient file I/O in Fortran77

Tags: file-io, fortran, fortran77

**Due to implementation constraints I have to use Fortran77**.

Some context - I am writing a finite element code and for each element I have the material law written in F77. For my material law I require information from external text files - therefore for each element, I am opening a text file, reading from it (2D array) and closing it. As you can imagine, as the number of elements goes up, the amount of I/O becomes very high. **The text files being read in are static - not changing per element or over time.**

The current read block looks as follows:

```
                open (xx, file='C:\Users\myfile.txt',status='old')
                C loop over the data points
                do k = 1, k_tot
                    do j = 1, j_tot
                          read(xx,*) alpha(j,1), alpha(j,k+1)
                    end do
                C close the file
                close (xx)
```

My question is - what would be the most efficient way to perform this I/O?
Reading in the entire array at once didn't really work - there is no compiler error but the array elements are unassigned, i.e.

```
                open (xx, file='C:\Users\myfile.txt',status='old')
                read(xx,*) alpha
                close (xx)
```

nor

```
                open (xx, file='C:\Users\myfile.txt',status='old', format = 'unformatted')
                read(xx) alpha
                close (xx)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Can you explain why you have to use Fortran 77? The example which you show for reading the whole array at once is Fortran 90, for example. Please explain what is *"it didn't work"*. This phrase does not tell anything useful. Did it compile? Did it run? Any error messages? Were the results correct? Was it slow or fast?

Comment: There is not.much you can do.if you need text files. Text files are always slow. The compiler must translate the text into numbers. If you need to.be fast, you need binary (unformatted) files.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I am using a commercial FE code which requires user materials to be in F77. For the other examples - it didn't give me an compile errors, rather the array remained unassigned. I generate the text file from MATLAB; so I could write out binary files, I will look into I/O with binary files as I do not have much experience with this.

Comment: please be specific what commercial code requires f77.  In any case you really ought to know if the file is text or binary, so why are you trying to read both ways?

Comment: Commercial code is Abaqus v2017, solver is Abaqus/Explicit. Well that's the exact reason for this question, I am not sure what is the fastest way to do it, so far I have been using ASCII files as they are easier to work with, but at this stage the proof of concept is done and I am looking at optimising the performance of the code. That could mean reading in the entire array at once, or using binary form (which I have 0 experience with (pun intended!)) or whatever. I understand the question is a bit general, I thought it would be a shortcut to sitting down with a F77 programming book.

Comment: abaqus does not at all need f77.  for best performance use binary files with `access=stream`  (thats fortran 2003 or so).  Reccomend practicing writing some stand alone program to read binary files first before putting it in your user subroutine.

Comment: Abaqus does NOT require Fortran 77.

Comment: @VladimirF "The example which you show for reading the whole array at once is Fortran 90, for example." Actually whole array I/O was in F77, and I think F66 as well. It was the only per-F90 whole array operation, possibly excepting data statements.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, bu then I didn't check. It wasn't too important. I would have to delete a big comments with other points in it.